# install gstreamer1.0-libav (mainly libavcodec54) on debian wheezy

Tags: debian, dependencies, gstreamer

I need to install gstreamer1.0 libraries.. I found that they are in wheezy-backports. So I added wheezy-backports to sources.list updated try ton install and stuck on dependency problems:

```
aptitude install gstreamer1.0-libav
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gstreamer1.0-libav{b} 
0 packages upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Need to get 166 kB of archives. After unpacking 353 kB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gstreamer1.0-libav : Depends: libavcodec54 (>= 6:9.1-1) which is a virtual package. or
                               libavcodec-extra-54 (>= 6:9.13) which is a virtual package.
                      Depends: libavformat54 (>= 6:9.1-1) which is a virtual package.
                      Depends: libavutil52 (>= 6:9.1-1) which is a virtual package.
                      Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 (>= 1.2.2) but it is not going to be installed.
                      Depends: libgstreamer1.0-0 (>= 1.2.0) but it is not going to be installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     gstreamer1.0-libav [Not Installed]                 



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n

*** No more solutions available ***
```

To install libavcodec54 is really impossible - its only in sid I dont know why. When I try to add sid repository I end up again in other dependency problems (with libavutil52)

Then I added testing jessie repository and install from there.. it somehow works, but I have problems loading some plugin:

```
gst-inspect-1.0 --version

(gst-plugin-scanner:16077): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstmpeg2dec.so': /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstmpeg2dec.so: undefined symbol: mpeg2_guess_aspect
gst-inspect-1.0 version 1.4.4
GStreamer 1.4.4
```

This error is show just once, when I run again it shows no error..

I know that gstreamer 1.0 is currently unstable .. but is there any correct way how to install it into debian 7 wheezy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found something on forum of debian: http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=118530&p=558557&hilit=how+install+gstreamer1.0#p558557 Its about that two developers made some changes and the result is that you cannot install gstreamer1.0-libav

Workaround is to use this repository, but I am not happy with it. http://www.deb-multimedia.org/ You have to use also wheezy-backports from that repository because of libavutil52 library which is only there..